# find parent of the opener iframe

Tags: javascript

lets say we have an iframe in page test1.html

```
<iframe src=test2.html"></iframe>
```

and there is a link in test2.html:

```
<a href="test3.html" target="_blank">open in new window"</a>
```

in test3.html how can I know the parent of the opener? (that is test1.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `window.opener.top` should get you the window object of the parent. From there you can get `.location.href`, or whatever you need. Keep in mind that browser restrictions will cause this to fail if any of the documents are on different domains.